# Firebase Cloud Messaging is not working on iOS 12

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoa-touch, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set up everything according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in

However, I am not receiving any messages.

My APN certificate (p.12) expired, I had to add a new APN key (p.8) (I think there is no issue here.)

I am not receiving anything in my log, after the app enters background.

Also, there are no error messages.

I am confused, it used to work on iOS 11.

What is my mistake here?

```
@implementation AppDelegate

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"APPDIDFINISHLAUNCH called with options: %@", launchOptions);
    [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"xxxxx";
    [FIRApp configure];
    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;

    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult * _Nullable result,
                                                    NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching remote instance ID: %@", error);
      } else {
        NSLog(@"Remote instance ID token: %@", result.token);
        NSString* message =
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Remote InstanceID token: %@", result.token];
      }
    }];

    if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
      [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
      UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
          UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
      [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
          requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          }];
    } else {
      UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
      (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
      UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
      [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
      [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
    NSLog(@"ssaging messaging].APNSToke");
}

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveMessage: %@", remoteMessage);
}

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {

    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fcmToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
     @"FCMToken" object:nil userInfo:dataDict];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {


  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

I am happy for any help.